# How to set friendly network name of android phone?

Tags: networking, android

I see names of computers in my router's DHCP leasing list. My android galaxy tab is listed under an alphanumeric name. How do I set a friendly name that I like?

Answer (score 30):

On Android 4.4 and lower, you can change the hostname to a less cryptic name in the Developer Options under Settings. Under the "Debugging" section in the Developer Options you will see an option called "Device hostname" which should currently be set to this rather cryptic name. You can change it to any alpha numeric name you like.

If you are on Android 5.0, that option is not there anymore. Though using the ADB shell still works. See [bayuah](https://superuser.com/users/166158/bayuah)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/408539/how-to-set-friendly-network-name-of-android-computer/863648#863648). Root doesn't seem to be required on my phone. From the answer linked above:

```
adb shell
getprop net.hostname
setprop net.hostname <new_hostname>
```

Comment: Sadly this option does not appear on a Bionic running rooted stock ROM 4.1.2.

Comment: Worked like a charm on my S3 running Cyanogenmod. :)

Comment: This option is not available anymore since Android 5.0.

Comment: You can try @bayuah answer. I tried it and works without root access on my Android 5.01 phone.

Comment: The adb method doesn't seem to work on Android 5.1 (and no option to use su for me, it says "/system/bin/sh: su: not found"). Tested on Moto E 2nd Gen with adb v1.0.32.

Comment: Does NOT work since Android 5.1 (including the adb method).

Comment: Did not work for me. Galaxy J7, android 6.0.1.
There were no errors reported, but the name simply did not change.

Answer (score 17):

Open terminal. Enter the following:

```
adb shell
su
getprop net.hostname
setprop net.hostname <new_hostname>
```

Root access is required.

Comment: it's sad that with no root access, it doesn't complain when you invoke setprop, it just doesn't take effect (checked with getprop). Also su fails for me: "/system/bin/sh: su: not found". Is that an indicator of device not rooted or that the device doesn't offer an su option? Or is this something missing in my ADB install?

Comment: Yes. It's either your device isn't support root access or you aren't manually rooting the device yet.

Comment: @David: "Is that an indicator of device not rooted or that the device doesn't offer an su option?" - Those are the same thing. A rooted device gives you the `su` command to gain root privileges from a shell; a non-rooted device doesn't have that command.

Comment: @bayuah - I can do this by opening a terminal program on my phone.  All the above commands work, and `getprop ...` returns the new hostname, even when I exit out of the `su`; but the hostname that is broadcast does not change, and it doesn't stick when I reboot.  Thoughts?

Comment: @Diagon What's your Android version? I was try it on my 4.1.1. Perhaps it's work for you: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/43559/69442. A little bit work though. Basically it's edit the `/system/build.prop` file.

Comment: @bayuah - I'm on 4.0.4.  Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look at that link.

Comment: One note4 6.0, the value gets reset after reboot.

Answer (score 13):

Hostname is used to easily identify and remember hosts connected to a network. It's set on boot, e.g. from `/etc/hostname` on Linux based systems. Hostname is also a part of `DHCPREQUEST` (standardized as [code 12](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dhc-fqdn-option-12#section-2.1) by IETF) which a DHCP client (Android device in our case) makes to DHCP server (WiFi router) to get an IP address assigned. DHCP server stores the hostnames to offer services like DNS. See details in [How to ping a local network host by hostname?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215878/218526).

Android - instead of using Linux kernel's [hostname service](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.hostname-name-service.html) - used property `net.hostname` (since Android [2.2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/de8383ca312c03fa8e935ac1549ae31ce668652c)) to set a unique host name for every device which was based on `android_id`. This hostname property was used for DHCP handshake (as added in Android [2.2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/9363b7d5da7e17842432251384f8dc46902ac323) and [4.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/dhcpcd/+/e86eee143ed21592f88a46623a81f71002430459/dhcpcd.conf#4)). In Android 6 `net.hostname` continued to be used <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-6.0.0_r1/services/net/java/android/net/dhcp/DhcpClient.java#395), [2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-6.0.0_r1/services/net/java/android/net/dhcp/DhcpPacket.java#1138), [3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-6.0.0_r1/services/net/java/android/net/dhcp/DhcpRequestPacket.java#67), [4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-6.0.0_r1/services/net/java/android/net/dhcp/DhcpPacket.java#597))</sup> in new [Java DHCP client](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a071edce46fa3d8d539c0d807b77147e184e5a51) when native `dhcpcd` was abandoned and later [service was removed](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/9c07eb9dd83a4b62a24836cc82a0ab5e7ae08f7d) in Android 7. Since Android 8 - when [`android_id` became unique](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219757/218526) to apps - `net.hostname` is [no more set](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/fc1b6a3f2abbcea391001165df2357c9b7397bbf), so a `null` is sent in `DHCPREQUEST`. See Android 8 [Privacy Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#privacy-all) and [Security Enhancements](https://source.android.com/security/enhancements/enhancements80):

> `net.hostname` is now empty and the dhcp client no longer sends a hostname

So the **WiFi routers show no host names for Android 8+, neither we can set / unset / change it.**

However **on rooted devices** you can set `net.hostname` manually using `setprop` command or add in some `init`'s `.rc` file to set on every boot. Or use a third party client like `busybox udhcpc` to send desired hostname and other options to router. See [Connecting to WiFi via ADB Shell](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219548/218526).

Answer (score 8):

In some Android phones, you may change in **`Wi-Fi Direct`**

1. Settings
2. WiFi
3. Top right menu > Advanced
4. Wi-Fi Direct
5. Top right option **Rename device**
6. Write your new device name and press **OK**
7. Turn off and on your Wi-Fi
8. If it has no effect, restart your phone.

**Important:** Not all Android phones have this option, and not all phones modify their hostname correctly, even after modifying the device name from that option.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Unfortunately I found it only after I changed hostname using `su & setprop`, but it is great to know this option is available.

Comment: My Moto G6 with Android 9 has that set already, but the router says the hostname is `--`.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to reference another related solution I came across using ADB (and requires rooted device): http://nileshgr.com/2012/10/13/how-to-change-wifi-host-name-of-your-android-device. I would however prefer the ADB commands presented here on SO than this link, but it's another method at least.

Comment: Only method I found that still works.  Other answers get clobbered on reboot, or simply don't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

On my Galaxy Edge S7 the device friendly name can be changed under "About phone" (near the bottom of the Settings menu):

[image: Screenshot of "About phone" panel]

Since I configured it to "Matthijs mobiel", our local router gave me the hostname "Matthijs-mobiel.fritz.box".  Unfortunately it sounds like your router might be assigning a name based on MAC address rather than based on the device friendly name, in which case this probably won't help (though you can try configuring a name that's a valid hostname already, perhaps it will work).

Answer (score 1):

The name that is sent to the DHCP server is not the hostname as is commonly thought, it's the VID (Vendor ID Code) which you cannot change. You could try changing the name at the router level if possible.

Comment: Is it possible to set hostname? Is it possible to set any name on Android?

Comment: You should be able to change it in the settings, otherwise rooting it will allow console access and you could change it through there.

Comment: I can find only Bluethooth name setting. Can you please point where other name settings can be located?

Comment: This is crazy, why are people down voting the truth ?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is using the commands posted by @bayuah above, but not using `adb` nor `su` at all.
This is on a rooted device (Nougat AOSP 7.1.2).
Using JuiceSSH terminal, enter two commands:

```
getprop net.hostname
setprop net.hostname <new_hostname>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 8.1 (possibly later as well) on Samsung Galaxy Tab...

Settings/About Tablet..."Edit"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

On LineageOS 10, I could simply search in the settings for `hostname` and it led me to

**System -> Developer Options -> Device hostname**

This answer of course requires to have developer options activated, but other than that it is possible that it also works on other android versions than LineageOS.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot and spending days over this, I'm going to share my experience with the community:

1. `udhcpc` [RECOMMENDED]
   [Udhcpc is a very small DHCP client program geared towards embedded systems. It's maintained as a part of `BusyBox`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udhcpc)
   To change the hostname with `udhcpc`  use the `-h` flag:
   `busybox udhcpc -x hostname:READABLE_HOSTNAME`
   It's persisted, and works prefect. It has more features you can read more about udchpc [here](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/8/udhcpc/#DESCRIPTION_693371833h).
2. Changing the `net.hostname` property
   `setproperty net.hostname READABLE_HOSTNAME`
   and to presist it you can append `net.hostname=READABLE_HOSTNAME` to the `/system/build.prop`

This solution might not work on some Android version, I had problems with Android 11. It was working perfectly on Android 10 but after upgrading to Android 11 it stopped working.
And be aware that touching the system files can be very dangerous and brick your device.

Answer (score 0):

On a RedMagic 9 Pro I was able to change the hostname without root using ADB

```bash
adb shell
settings put --user current global device_name Peregrin
```